# Calculate surface area of each material?

Tags: python

How to find the surface area of different parts of a mesh depending on the materials assigned with python?

Answer (score 1):

Extending the answer from [surface area of a mesh using Python code in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47675/surface-area-of-a-mesh-using-python-code-in-blender)

```
import bpy
import bmesh

#active object
obj = bpy.context.active_object
# bmesh of active object
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(obj.data)
#material slots
for i, slot in enumerate(obj.material_slots):     
    area = sum(f.calc_area() for f in bm.faces
               if f.material_index == i)
    print("Material %d Area %.4f" % (i, area))

bm.free()
```