# Count of multiple face areas

Tags: mesh, faces, mathematics, measurement

is any way how to display total faces area of selected faces in Blender 2.8? Manually counting isnt possible...I want count 1000 and more faces...

[image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47675/surface-area-of-a-mesh-using-python-code-in-blender

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me in Blender 2.82.  Result is shown in System Console window.

```
import bpy

bpy.context.object.update_from_editmode() 
#applies any pending edits.
#allows script to be run from within edit mode

the_area = 0
for poly in bpy.context.object.data.polygons:
    if poly.select:
        the_area += poly.area

print('final area total')
print(the_area)
```

Comment: Thank you it works excellent for me too ^^...(I tried the the MeasureIt addon, but it doesnt work - it looks like measureIt infinitely counts the area... so my computer almost freeze. Larger area = bigger freezing.) Thank you for this script :)

Comment: Or `area = sum(p.area for p in me.polygons if p.select)`  Worth noting too that this is local values, eg default cube with subsurf and scaled to 0 will still have face area 6x2x2