# What is the technique or method blender uses to calculate surface area of mesh from print 3d tool box?

Tags: mesh, materials, mathematics

I know we can obtain the surface area and volume of mesh from print 3d tool box. I want to know what is the technique blender uses to obtain them.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47675/surface-area-of-a-mesh-using-python-code-in-blender#comment81086_47676