# Persistence of element tag and select using bound bmesh

Tags: python, scripting, edit-mode, bmesh

For bmesh code I often used  `tag` to flag a visited element.  On noticing the tags persisted it was required to "detag" the entire bmesh element collection on each run, for consistent results.

Have used a workaround of tagging via a default dictionary as demoed here https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/199075/15543

Below is a little test script to run in edit mode. Randomly tags and selects. Does not have a call to update the edit bmesh so the selection does not show in the edit window.  Run enough times and all edges are tagged.

If the object is toggled back into edit mode the selection persists, all tags are reset to default of `False`

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from random import choice

context = bpy.context
ob = context.object
me = ob.data

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

print("Selected", len([e for e in bm.edges if e.select]))
print("Tagged", len([e for e in bm.edges if e.tag]))

for e in bm.edges:
    e.tag = e.tag or choice((True, False))
    e.select_set(e.tag)
```

Is there a way to quickly discard any selection made or tag set without iterating and resetting all elements?